# Flatpickr initialisation fail

Tags: javascript, calendar, flatpickr

I'm having trouble initializing the flatpickr from the input value.

This is the flatpickr HTML:

```
<div class="flatpickr">
<input name="test" value="2019-07-03" type="text" data-input>
<a class="input-button" title="toggle" data-toggle><i class="icon-calendar"></i></a>
</div>
```

This is the the config:

```
flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
    dateFormat: "d.m.Y",    
    weekNumbers: true,
    wrap: true
});
```

The calendar get initialized with the date **20.09.2019** but it should be **03.07.2019**.

I also tried setting the date to a timestamp, but the initialization goes wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dateFormat` in the `value` attribute should match the `dateFormat: "d.m.Y"`

```js
flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
  dateFormat: "d.m.Y",
  weekNumbers: true,
  wrap: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<div class="flatpickr">
  <input name="test" value="03.07.2019" type="text" data-input>
  <a class="input-button" title="toggle" data-toggle>
    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought flatpickr can process this. See: https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#supplying-dates-for-flatpickr

Comment: It works only with the mentioned options not with value attribute. Else you can use `defaultDate`. Also Date Strings, which must match the dateFormat chronologically